# How do I set videopath for UDP stream using vitamio?

Tags: java, android-studio, stream, vitamio

I'm trying to get a UDP stream from a GoPro camera.
https://github.com/KonradIT/GoProStream

I'm redoing this python code in android studio using vitamio.
But for some reason, as soon as I set the path, it crashes

```
_myVideoView.setVideoPath("udp://@10.5.5.100:8554");
```

But if I remove it, the app can launch but of course there is no video.
If someone encountered the same issue and found a solution, that would help me.

```
_myVideoView.setVideoPath("udp://@10.5.5.100:8554");
_myVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
_myVideoView.setBufferSize(2048);
_myVideoView.requestFocus();
_myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
_myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // optional need Vitamio 4.0
        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
    }
});

_myVideoView.start();
```

I have done that for onCreate :

```
if(!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)){
            return;
        }
        Vitamio.initialize(this);
```

the videoview :

```
<io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButtonLeft"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/WebView"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
```

and the build graddle :

```
implementation project(path: ':vitamio')
```

ps : I've tried to put the compile line in graddle, but it can't find the method compile and the implement line seem to work just fine.

ps2 : I just tried but even http link from YouTube doesn't work, I've definitely made a mistake but dunno where

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...

I was just importing the project but I didn't build it beforehand
So there was no way it could work.

But I gave up later for other reasons and I would recommend lib vlc instead of vitamio for displaying video from udp streams.